# Higher-dimensional analogue of the cuboctahedron

Tags: geometry

In my future questions, I would like to reference a 16-dimensional shape. Its three-dimensional version is the cuboctahedron, and its four-dimensional version is the 24-cell.

Coordinates of the cuboctahedron:
\begin{align*}
(\pm 1, \pm 1, 0) \
(\pm 1, 0, \pm 1) \
(0, \pm 1, \pm 1)
\end{align*}

Coordinates of the 24-cell:
\begin{align*}
(\pm 1, \pm 1, 0, 0) \
(\pm 1, 0, \pm 1, 0) \
(0, \pm 1, \pm 1, 0) \
(0, 0, \pm 1, \pm 1) \
(0, 0, \pm 1, 0, \pm 1) \
(\pm 1,0,0, \pm 1)
\end{align*}

This 16-dimensional shape has 480 points with coordinates:
\begin{align*}
(\pm 1, \pm 1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0) \
(\pm 1, 0, \pm 1, 0, \ldots, 0) \
(0, \pm 1, \pm 1, 0, \ldots, 0) \
(0, 0, \pm 1, \pm 1, \ldots, 0) \
\ldots \
(0, 0, \ldots, 0, \pm 1, 0, \pm 1) \
(0, 0, 0, \ldots, 0, \pm 1, \pm 1)
\end{align*}

What is the name of this 16-dimensinal shape, and how can I reference it in the future?